1980-90 Cartoon with rainbows and bears in the ending that had a very beautiful catchy song?
It's not Care Bears but it's from around that time up to the 90's. The ending had an animation of the land, with bears, magic flying carpets, rainbow waterfalls or something along those lines, basically the land that the cartoon is based on with a very beautiful, catchy ending theme song.
'Bright Eyes' reminds me somewhat of the ending song but it's not the Watership Down movie.

Is "it has bears and rainbows" the only thing you remember about it? What did the bears look like? What was the story all about? etc

I was too young but I have a distinct memory of that ending.

How did you exclude Care Bears? By story alone or general appearance? Don't forget there's been a series as well as a movie.

Could you be remembering a bit of Teddy Ruxpin? Admittedly it's not a Movie, but the intro might fit. It has got a bear and a rainbow waterfall, and something flying, even if it is not a carpet:




Given that you've said it wasn't Care Bears, but was from around the same time, and also the rainbows and the ending song being something like "Bright Eyes", could it be Rainbow Brite?
There was a tv series and an animated movie.
The movie had a song, which might be the one you remember:




Was it Gummi Bears by Disney?
I remember lots of rainbows and bears there.

Could you elaborate? Can't find any rainbows or flying carpets in the intro, and in the end credits there's just a still image of a tree. But if was fun to reminisce. :)

ok, it wasn't rainbows exactly, but this used to be popular back in the 90s. this is the opening track: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRTSZZgCUik
